# Getting a weird error after upgrading a VS2008/.NET FX 2.0 project to VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

After the upgrade, when build, a warning pops up saying:

> The primary reference "Elegant.Ui.Ribbon, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3a2b400713aae6e0, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework. PDFFlowline.VS2010

How so? And how to fix it. This project compiles fine on VS2008. I'm running Windows 7 and VS2010  and both of them have the latest updates installed.

Comment: One of your main projects is still referencing 2.0

Comment: Yes, I'm not upgrading framework, I'm merely upgrading visual studio. But when I choose .NET 4.0 as the target framework, more errors occur, hundreds of.

Comment: How many projects are in your solution ?

Comment: Just one. I managed to use SharpDevelop as I don't want to get in the hassle of installing VS2008, it's both expensive and too bulky for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot get it to work on VS2010, instead I tried SharpDevelop which can open and build projects of older version, in this case VS2008. So my problem solved, sort of. 
BTW, to get it to work, you need to set the target framework to 2.0 and C# compiler to 3.0 if you are planning to use lambda, LINQ with LINQBridge and Extension Methods which is an essential part of my C# coding.